# Is it possible to only run a jbehave scenario if it has a metatag

Tags: meta, jbehave

I was wondering if it was possible to exlude everything without a specifik metatag using the metafilter. say I have this story:

```
Story: My story

Scenario:first scenario
Meta:
@runThis

Scenario:second scenario

Scenario:third scenario
Meta:
@runThis
```

Now I only want to run the once with the meta @runThis, but the meta filter only allows me to explicitly add a tag or remove a tag. I can't tell it to only play my tags. If all scenarios had the tag with a true/false value instead I could do this:

```
embedder.useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("+runThis true","-runThis false"));
```

But that's not what I have to work with, anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [JBehave Documentation](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html)

```
Embedder embedder = ... // define as required
embedder.useMetaFilters(asList("+author Mauro", "+theme filtering", "-skip"));
```

I think the key in this example is the "asList(" however, from my reading of the Meta Filters, simply specifying +runThis should suffice.

Comment: yeah but the +runThis just says what should be run, not what shouldn't be run that's why there's a -skip for example